# Pinescript multiple strategy.exit for one entry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I try to create two different strategy.exit function for one entry(one of them is for limit, other one is for stop). Because I want to take different comments from these two exit function.

Related code snippet:

```
strategy.entry("Longi" , direction = strategy.long, limit = close + 5)
strategy.exit("LongKapa" , from_entry = "Longi" , limit = xxx)
strategy.exit("LongKapa" , from_entry = "Longi" , stop = xxx)
```

But strategy tester neglect second one. So how can I get two different comments without using strategy.order in if block ?

Answer (score 3):

You should give it unique id's otherwise you will `modify` and not `create` a new one.

```
strategy.entry("Longi" , direction = strategy.long, limit = close + 5, qty=2)
strategy.exit("LongKapa-1" , from_entry = "Longi" , limit = xxx, qty=1)
strategy.exit("LongKapa-2" , from_entry = "Longi" , stop = xxx, qty=1)
```

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}exit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit)

Answer (score 1):

Use logical `or`. Applicable to boolean expressions.

```
longCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 20), ta.sma(close, 50))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)


exitCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 10), ta.sma(close, 20)) or ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 10), ta.sma(close, 50))
if (exitCondition)
    strategy.exit("exit", "My Long Entry Id", profit = 10, loss = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`strategy.exit` has dedicated comment arguments for that purpose: `comment, comment_profit, comment_loss, comment_trailing`, which are used based on the condition, which triggered the exit. Check help for details, but in your example you'd use:

```
strategy.exit("LongKapa" , from_entry = "Longi" ,
  limit = xxx, stop = xxx,
  comment_profit = 'Limit triggered',
  comment_loss = 'Stop triggered'
  )
```